# XPDL 2.x Supporting BPMS

Tags: business-process-management

Can anyone please suggest me any java based opensourse BPMS which supports import / export of XPDL 2.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently ProcessMaker is working on it. If you download the current stable (2.0.31) there is a function to import the XPDL. Unfortunately, it is still in an very early stage.  So, if you find any bugs please report them to make the import better.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/processmaker/files/ProcessMaker/2.0/2.0.31/